# redirection of ./a.out is not capturing segmentation fault

Tags: c++, c, linux, bash, shell

I run the command

```
./a.out < in &> output.txt
```

I want the errors also to be placed in `output.txt`.
The `exit` status of the command was 139 and on terminal its output was:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

and the file `output.txt` was empty.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The message `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` is *not* coming from your program.

It's produced by shell as result of a signal received by it. It's not a part of *stderr* or *stdout* of your program.

So shell's message can be captured as:

```
{ ./a.out; } 2> out_err
```

Comment: bash: syntax error near unexpected token `}' was the output of command at terminal and bash: {./a.out}: No such file or directory
was the content of output.txt.

Comment: @chandankharbanda You need whitespaces before & after `{` and `}` and `;` to terminate the command (as in my post). I think you are executing it as `{./a.out} 2>out_err` not as `{ ./a.out; } 2>out_err`.

Comment: ya got it i was not using whitespaces after and before { and } respectively.

Comment: Interestingly, this doesn't work when I want to redirect both cout and cerr while preserving the output to the terminal, by using the `{ ./a.out; } |& tee out_err` syntax.

Answer (score 5):

If you want both the error messages from `a.out` and the string

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

to be appended to `output.txt`, then you have to redirect the shell's `stderr` as well.  E.g.,

```
exec 2>> output.txt && ./a.out < in 2>&1 >> output.txt &
```

This is because the *segfault* message is coming from the shell itself.