# core dumped message is not captured in STDERR

Tags: c++, linux, bash

I used to call my program with this line in bash shell to capture all stdout and stderr messages in the log file

```
./a.out input.txt 2>&1 | tee log
```

The log file shows no error but by examining the log, it's obvious that there's a problem and program terminates abruptly in the middle of execution.

I have also tried these but the result is the same:

```
./a.out input.txt > log 2>&1

./a.out input.txt |& tee log
```

When I run it without any redirection like this:

```
./a.out input.txt
```

I see the error message in my terminal window at the end:

```
*** Error in `./a.out': free(): invalid pointer: 0x000000000169b268 ***
Aborted (core dumped)
```

So, why I cannot capture the "core dumped" message in my log? What should I do to do so?

Comment: Some programs only print certain messages to stderr when it's connected to a tty (text terminal, which you can interpret as an interactive shell). Those messages might be suppressed when stderr is connected to a pipe.

Comment: My guess is that your shell is printing the "Error in x: free()" etc. messages after the program with redirected output crashes.  You could try running the process in a subshell: `$( ./a.out ) > log > 2>&1` - I'd try but don't have a Linux box handy.

Comment: I wrote the program and I didn't do anything special whether it's connected to tty or not. It's a simple program I wrote for recursive merge sort with dynamic arrays and deletion of them. I compiled with g++ in ubuntu.

Comment: You don't need to do anything special; it could be the compiler.

Comment: You could try this with a pseudo tty, and see if you get the message.

Comment: Try `cat /proc/$$/limits` on Linux. You might have disabled [core(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html) dump with [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) perhaps using your shell's `ulimit` builtin. Then compile your program with all warnings & debug info (`g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`) and use the debugger (`gdb`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 2 error messages here:

```
*** Error in `./a.out': free(): invalid pointer: 0x000000000169b268 ***
```

This comes from glibc, and is printed on the current tty, if it exists.

If you want it printed to stderr (wherever stderr is redirected), you must set
the `LIBC_FATAL_STDERR_` prior to starting the program. 
e.g. in bash do:

```
export LIBC_FATAL_STDERR_=1
```

The other message

```
Aborted (core dumped)
```

This comes from the shell that started your program, by the shell examining the status of [wait](http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait)().
If the program isn't run by a shell, or e.g. is run by a shell that have terminated, you'll not be able to capture that message. Even if the shell havn't terminated, the stderr of that shell isn't redirected to your log file.

You might get around that by doing:

```
 { ./a.out input.txt ; } >log 2>&1
```

See also [redirection of ./a.out is not capturing segmentation fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23954607/redirection-of-a-out-is-not-capturing-segmentation-fault))

Comment: The first recommendation about LIBC_FATAL_STDERR_ is right. I see the "*** Error..." in the log now. However, second recommendation doesn't work. Even with parenthesis, "Aborted" message is still in the terminal window, not in the log.

Comment: Yes, apparently you need the bracers, and not parenthesis (that spawns a subshell) . Though it's unclear as to why a sub shell doesn't work.