# How can I write C++ crash errors in a file?

Tags: c++, stderr

**Context:**

A C++ program is at the heart of a python routine. This program seems to fail at some point but I am unable to pinpoint the error since nothing is written to my log files.

It lead me to realise that, while `std::cout` and `std::cerr` would respectively write to the stdout and stderr sterams, other errors (e.g., `Floating point exception`) are not written to any of these streams (please correct me if I am wrong).

**Minimal working example:**

Consider `test.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() { cout << "cout" << endl; cerr << "cerr" << endl; cout << 1/0 << endl; }
```

and compile it using `g++ test.cpp -o test`.

Executing the script with

```
./test 1> stdout 2> stderr
```

writes "cout" to stdout, "cerr" to stderr, as expected, but writes "Floating point exception" directly into my terminal window.

Is there a way to write this error in a file?

Comment: You can catch the arithmetic exception in try-catch block and use std::cout to log info e.what(). std::exception e; e -> provide the what() to get the exception details.

Comment: That's because `Floating point exception` is not the output of your program but of your operating system. `1>` and `2>` redirect the output of your program. You could try to start your program in a new shell and redirect its output `$(./test) > error.log`. I didn't test it and I don't know if it works.

Comment: Nice first question OP!

Comment: @ThomasSablik Is there a way to write the output of my OS in a file then or does this not make any sense?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [redirection of ./a.out is not capturing segmentation fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23954607/redirection-of-a-out-is-not-capturing-segmentation-fault)

Comment: Many thanks @miszcz2137, this is the kind of trick I was looking for!